# ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 16

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

https://medium.com/@francoisromain/host-multiple-websites-with-https-inside-docker-containers-on-a-single-server-18467484ab95

Used the commands in the link above to create my environment.

I've created the proxy with jwilder/nginx-proxy.  But getting errors when trying to run the webapp to connect to the proxy.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: node:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run dev
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
services:
  my-app:
    …
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: my-app.local
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 3000
services:
  my-app:
    …
    expose:
      - 3000
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: could you please indent your compose and put ?

Comment: Which line is line 24?

Comment: The error is generated by the three dots (`...`). They where meant by the author of the article to indicate omission of service definitions.

Comment: Thanks!  So, what do I put in place of the ...?